# Redshift Query Syntax error (using SQL Workbench): Is there an easy way to go directly to the "position" mentioned in the error?

Tags: position, syntax-error, amazon-redshift, sql-workbench-j

Is there an easy way to go directly to the position mentioned in an error message in SQL Workbench/Redshift (error provided below the code)? Thanks!

Here is the error:

> An error occurred when executing the SQL command:
>
> select
>       application_id,
>       case when stage_name in (
>         'Application Review',
>         'New Lead',
>         'Recruiter Review',
>         'Reached Out', ...
>
> Amazon Invalid operation: syntax error at or near ")" 
>    **Position: 201**; [SQL State=42601, DB Errorcode=500310] 1 statement
>    failed.
>
> Execution time: 0.16s

Here's the Query:

```
    select
    application_id,
    case when stage_name in (
      'Application Review',
      'New Lead',
      'Recruiter Review',
      'Reached Out',
      'Make Decision',
      'Resume Review',
    ) then 'Application Review' 
    when stage_name in ('Preliminary Phone Screen', 'Recruiter Screen','Handoff','Researcher Screen','Exploratory') then 'Recruiter Screen' 
    when stage_name in (
      'Phone Interview',
      'Phone Interview 2'
      'Phone Interview #1',
      'Phone Interview #2',
      'Phone/Initial Interview #1',
      'Phone/Initial Interview #2',
      'Hiring Manager Review',
      'Hiring Manager Screen',
      'Final Interview',
      'Take Home Test',
      'Initial Interview') 
      then 'Initial Interview' 
    when stage_name in 
    ( 'Onsite Interview #1',
      'Face to Face',
      'Face to Face 2',
      'Onsite Interview #2',
      'Onsite Interview') 
      then 'Onsite Interview' 
    when stage_name = 'Homework' then 'Homework' when stage_name in 
    ( 'Post Onsite',
      'Reference Check',
      'Hiring Review',
      'Hiring Review Debrief',
      'Hiring Review/Debrief',
      'Post Hiring Review / Debrief',
      'Post Hiring Review/Post Debrief',
      'Hiring Review / Debrief',
      'Post Hiring Review / Post Debrief',
      'Team Match') 
      then 'Post Onsite' 
    when stage_name = 'Byteboard Interview' then 'Byteboard Interview' 
    when stage_name IN ('Filtered','Filtered.ai Matching') then 'Filtered' 
    when stage_name = 'HackerRank Test' then 'HackerRank Test' 
    when stage_name = 'ClassMarker' then 'ClassMarker'
when stage_name = 'Offer' then 'Offer' 
else 'Other' end as app_Stage_Name_group,
    min(entered_on) as entered_on,
    max(exited_on) as exited_on
  from
    application_stages
  where
    entered_on is not null
  group by
    1,
    2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Build 125, you can configure this through `workbench.settings` by using the same settings that are used for Postgres to identify the error position.

Edit the file with a regular text editor and add these two lines:

```
workbench.db.redshift.errorinfo.regex.position=(?i)position:\\s+[0-9]+
workbench.db.redshift.errorinfo.leading.comment.included=true
```

Then the cursor should automatically jump to the position in the editor identified by the error message.

The settings file is located in the [configuration directory](https://www.sql-workbench.eu/manual/install.html#config-dir). The exact location is shown in the about dialog and the options dialog.

Make sure you close SQL Workbench/J before editing the file.